# Where is $f(x+iy) = x^2y^2$ complex differentiable?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Here's my proof attempt:

$$f(x+iy) = x^2y^2$$

Applying Cauchy Riemann conditions:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2xy^2 = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$$

only when $x=0$ or $y=0$.

The second condition is:

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0 = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 2yx^2$$

only when $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Here, I do not have $x=0$ and $y=0$ at the same time, so what can I say about the set where this function can be complex differentiable?

Since the partial derivatives are continuous, this funciton will be differentiable wherever the Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied.

Comment: it is not **XOR** but **OR**, in common language **AND/OR**.

Comment: Hm, just wondering, are $x,y\in\mathbb R$?  (I'm not familiar with this stuff)  Also, what if $x=y$?  When $x=y$, I think $f(z)$ is complex differentiable?

Comment: @SimpleArt yes, they are reals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cauchy-Riemann conditions are satisfied on points where either $x=0$ or $y=0$ (or both). They aren't satisfied when $x\ne0$ *and* $y\ne0$.

Since the two variable function $(x,y)\mapsto x^2y^2$ is everywhere real-differentiable, the CR conditions guarantee complex-differentiability where they hold. Where they don't hold the function is not complex-differentiable.

Just for a check, suppose we are at $x+i0$; then, for $h=a+ib$,
$$
f(x+h)=f((x+a)+ib)=(x+a)^2b^2
$$
so
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{(x+a)^2b^2}{a+ib}
$$
Then
$$
\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|=(x+a)^2b\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
\xrightarrow[a+ib\to0]{}0
$$
The same at points on the imaginary axis.

Comment: Why $x=y=1$ won't satisfy the CR conditions?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Because $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\big|_{(1,1)}=2$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\big|_{(1,1)}=0$.